# Why am i getting Unable to load shared library 'IronPdf_ChromeRenderingEngine' when I use Renderer.RenderHtmlAsPdf with IronPdf?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, .net-core

I have a .net core 2.1 project configured with docker (Debian GNU/Linux). I'm using PDF.Core 5.2.0.

When it gets on the `RenderHtmlAsPdf` method in the code below I get this error : `193:    binding file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 [0] to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 [0]: normal symbol _Unwind_Resume_or_Rethrow' [GCC_3.3]
       193: symbol=_Unwind_RaiseException;  lookup in file=/usr/bin/dotnet [0]
       193: symbol=_Unwind_RaiseException;  lookup in file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 [0]
       193: symbol=_Unwind_RaiseException;  lookup in file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 [0]
       193: symbol=_Unwind_RaiseException;  lookup in file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 [0]
       193: symbol=_Unwind_RaiseException;  lookup in file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 [0]
       193: symbol=_Unwind_RaiseException;  lookup in file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 [0]
       193: binding file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 [0] to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 [0]: normal symbol _Unwind_RaiseException' [GCC_3.0]
Exception thrown: 'System.DllNotFoundException' in IronPdf.Core.dll: 'Unable to load shared library 'IronPdf_ChromeRenderingEngine' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libIronPdf_ChromeRenderingEngine: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'
Stack trace:
at 맬.릺.wkhtmltopdf_init(Int32 useGraphics)
at 맬.맢.Load()
'`

I tried to run the project without docker on a windows 10 OS and I have no problem with the same code. Only with docker/linux.

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var Renderer = new IronPdf.HtmlToPdf();
    //following line is causing the error
    var PDF = Renderer.RenderHtmlAsPdf("<h1>Hello test</h1>");
    var OutputPath = "HtmlToPDF.pdf";
    PDF.SaveAs(OutputPath);
}
```

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to this issue?

Comment: No sorry, could not find how to fix it

Comment: I reached out to their support and after a few weeks they got back to me and updated their doco https://ironpdf.com/docs/questions/docker-linux/

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused by missing dependencies in the slim docker image. IronPDF have updated their documentation with the required steps to install all dependencies that are needed when converting html2pdf https://ironpdf.com/docs/questions/docker-linux/

Comment: Working for me still in 2021!